# Can't np.array.dot(np.array())

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Good evening, where is the problem?

```
F = FUN(X0)
J = jacobian(X0)
X1 = X0 - F.dot(np.linalg.inv(J))
```

where
X0 is:

```
[[1]
 [1]]
```

F is

```
[[ 5]
 [-2]]
```

np.linalg.inv(J) is

```
[[0.125 0.375]
 [0.375 0.125]]
```

and in result I expect

```
[[first_value]
[sec_value]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post an MCVE. Show the example you have with the values you claim raising the error you forgot to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred

Which is the case with your example. However you would not be able to do `F @ inverse_J` since `F` is `2x1` and `inverse_J` is `2x2`. I'm not sure what the output you expect is but if you do: `X0 - inverse_J @ F` you get:

```
array([[ 1.125],
       [-0.625]])
```

which is the shape you were looking for